# Android app shows home screen when going between activities

Tags: android, android-activity

In my app, when going from one activity to another and switching content views, for about a second the home screen is shown. I've tried adding a loading screen in, but the home screen is still shown, when going from an activity to the loading screen. So finally i tried switching from my mainmenu activity to a blank activity and it still showed the home screen for about a second. Any ideas on how to get rid of the home screen being shown between activities?

I am currently using intents to go between activities.

Comment: post some code, so we can help you more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out that I was setting the theme to noTitleBar and trying to remove it programmatically, by just setting the theme to DeviceDefault.noTitleBar the lag is gone.

Answer (score 3):

Call `startActivity()` and *then* `finish()` rather than the other way around.

Or, simply, don't call `finish()` on your current activity. The default behaviour in an app is that pressing `back` takes you to the previous activity, this won't be the case if the previous activity has been `finish`ed()

Comment: Thanks for your answer, he only time I'm calling finish() is when the back button is pressed, so it goes back to the previous activity. E.g  

public void showOptions(View view){
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, OptionsActivity.class);
  startActivity(intent);
 }

Then in the next activity I get the intent and only finish it on back button pressed.

Comment: in your next Activity are you calling setContentView() in your onCreate() without any `wait()` or `Thread.sleep()` ?

Comment: yeah setContentView is this first thing I call in each activity

Comment: Load up one of the Sample apps and see if that is having the same issue.

Comment: So turns out that I was setting the theme to noTitleBar and trying to remove it programmatically, by just setting the theme to DeviceDefault.noTitleBar the lag is gone. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should post that as an answer to your question, letting other people with your problem know that's what your problem was. Plus it will increase your rep so you'll get more help the next time you ask a question on here. :)

Comment: @Graeme This is 2 years old at this point but I wanted to comment that I'm developing a multimedia-intensive app for Google Glass for work and we keep having this exact same issue. In between my activities the "ok glass" home screen pops up for a second or two which totally breaks the user flow. It is probably super bad "best practices" but I tried removing instances of finish() and that seems to resolve my issue, albeit imperfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Please call the `finish()` after you created intent and just before you start your intent (i.e.) just before the statement `startActivity(intent);`